# Total number of cliques and anti-cliques

Tags: graph-theory

Most of the results I can find about cliques and anticliques are about clique number/independence number. I would like to know about the total number of cliques and anticliques: the more cliques, the less anticliques we can have.

The upper bound is $2^n$ (complete graph). A trivial lower bound would be $n(n-1)/2$ (because every time you add a vertex you create an $1$-clique and a total of $n$ 2-cliques (edges) and 2-anticliques (non-edges). Is there a better lower bound for the total number of cliques and anticliques?

Answer (score 1):

You could get nontrivial lower bounds from the Ramsey numbers. E.g. if $n \geq 6$, then $n$ must have a clique or anticlique of size $3$. And every $k$-clique gives you $\binom{k}{1}$-many $(k-1)$-cliques, $\binom{k}{2}$-many $(k-2)$-cliques, etc... so you get $2^k$ cliques in total. So a lower bound might be
$$\max \{ 2^k: n \geq R(k) \}$$

Perhaps a more careful analysis would give a tighter bound. If $R(k) \sim O(2^{k-\varepsilon})$ then this bound is exponential: I'm not sure if this is the case.

But in general, bounding your quantity is probably about as hard as bounding the Ramsey numbers, so I think you will struggle to get decent bounds on it.

Comment: It would be nice if it were exponential because I would expect the number of cliques/anticliques to be a lot more than the number of vertices, but the best upper bound on $R(k)$ seems to be a power of 4. As a result this bound would be less than # of vertices, correct?